# Get file hash (sha256sum) of file from multiple git commits

Tags: git, sha256

I want to get `SHA256` of all versions of a file in a git repos.
(In this case there is binary blobs in a repo, and want to find from which commit in a different repo they came from)

We can use `git show $hash:$file | sha256sum` to get this for one commit.

Bash example that I want to avoid:

```sh
for h in $(git log --pretty=format:"%H" -- $file)
do
  git show $h:$file | sha256sum
done
```

#### Is there any way to do this for all commits with "git only"? (avoid running from bash)

Preferably inside `git log` formatting to get more data.

###### Clarification:

Running bash "inside git" is fine, but I would like to avoid to have to run the command from bash so that is usable in both bash and powershell.

I can also not think that my hack is the best way to get checksums of each version of file in a git repo.

There has been recommendations of looking at [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974632/how-to-list-all-sha1-hash-a-specific-file-already-had) it uses internal `sha1` and has answers with bash.

Comment: Does it have to be SHA256, or would SHA1 be ok? Because git itself stores everything based on a sha1 hash, so you will probably be able to display that without actually fetching the file contents.

Comment: This seems impressively similar [to this recently asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974632/how-to-list-all-sha1-hash-a-specific-file-already-had).

Comment: @IMSoP I would prefer sha256 to keep it the same as some other checksum files that already exists.

Comment: @Joachim indeed very similar, but specific to SHA1/internal hash.

Comment: @NiKiZe: I'm aware, which is why I didn't vote to close as duplicate. But you could take the result of that question and feed it into further hash calculation: it'll already give you the details you need to grab the actual file content for each change.

Comment: @Joachim Don't seem to be able to find how it can help at all, I already have relevant commit ids and looping over them, grabbing contents and checksum, What I wanted to avoid was the outer bash - I would be perfectly fine with having `git log` execute bash.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to avoid here? I mean, "I don't want to type the letters b, a, s and h in sequence" isn't going to get a lot of sympathy and you're asking people to put in a lot of effort to avoid a problem you haven't specified in any more detail than pretty much exactly that.

Comment: @jthill I want to run this in a portable way (work on both win and nix) I'm fine with git starting its shell, but I tried to avoid starting bash from powershell and then run the command.

Comment: You want to script applying sha256sum to a selection of files from a vcs history, you have to pick a scripting language and you have to pick your vcs.  The tools are portable: shells, vcs's, la la, but at some point you have to choose specific tools and use them.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not use SHA256 (not yet, at least not by default), and the hash IDs that Git *does* use for blob objects are those for the blob objects, not for the straight file contents.  (This is why the answer to [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452) is "it doesn't".)

Hence, if you want to compute SHA256 values for specific files, you must extract the files contents and run a SHA256 computation on them.  Your bash example is more or less a minimal way to achieve what you want; you can't get much shorter without writing your own program.

Comment: I fully expect `sha256` to be needed externally, I was mostly hoping to avoid having to do external looping.

Comment: If your sha256 program takes multiple input arguments and you can extract each committed file to a separate in-file-system file, you can invert the loop: `sha256 $(scan-for-files)` for instance. But either way there's still a loop.